# change color if due date within 3 days from current date php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 variables,

```
$current_date = "27-05-2017";
$due_date = "29-05-2017";
```

All the above date is dynamic which is fetched from mysql. `$due_date` will change.

If the `$due_date` is within +3 days from the `$due_date`, then the color should change.

For example,

If `$current_date = "27-05-2017"` and `$due_date = "28-05-2017", $due_date = "29-05-2017", $due_date = "30-05-2017"` the color should be `orange`.

If `$current_date = "27-05-2017"` and `$due_date = "31-05-2017", $due_date = "01-06-2017"` the color should be `blue`.

I have tried using the below code.

```
$due_date = "30-05-2017";
$cur_date = "27-05-2017";

if($due_date > strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($cur_date)) or $due_date < strtotime("+2 day", strtotime($cur_date)) or $due_date < strtotime("+3 day", strtotime($cur_date)))
    echo "orange";
else
    echo "blue";
```

The code not working for all the conditions. How to fix this.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do with one condition:

```
$due_date = "30-05-2017";
$cur_date = "27-05-2017";

if(strtotime($due_date) > strtotime($cur_date) && strtotime($due_date) <= strtotime("$cur_date +3 day"))

    echo "orange";
else
    echo "blue";
```

Comment: if `$due_date` less than `$cur_date` the color should be `blue`. for example `26-05-2017, 25-05-2017...`

Comment: if `$due_date` equal to `$cur_date` the color should be blue. for example `$due_date = 27-05-2017`. Actually I forgot about this condition.

Comment: Mohammad's answer is the simple one, but if you're doing date comparisons you should take a look at the [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) library.